# ESP32 to GCP IOT Core connection failing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-pubsub, esp32

I want my data to move from iot device (esp32) to gcp iot core to cloud pub/sub. The issue is when I pull a message from pub/sub subscription the message body field displays "device-esp32-connected" rather than the actual json message that esp32 had sent.

My json file's structure is like:

```
{
    "Key1":"Value1",
    "Key2":"Value1",
    "Key3":"Value1",
    "List1": [
        {
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2",
            "key3":"value3"
        },
        {
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2",
            "key3":"value3"
        }
    ]
}
```

My actual json has a lot more fields in the "list1" list. It works if I decrease the number of fields but I cannot decrease the number of fields for my project.

Comment: If you share a minimal, viable example of the code which demonstrates this problem someone might help you. Otherwise you're asking people to guess at what your code is actually doing.

Comment: I have edited my question. The problem is probably related to Google IoT Core. Their limit for Telemetry event payload is 256 KB according to official documentation. But I am getting issues with less than 10 KB payload.

Comment: In order to proper investigate, could you share your code with send the message to pubsub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred due to the embedded code in esp32. The memory size I was setting for the message was less than the actual size of the message. Once I increased the allocated size the process started to work properly. I changed this:

```
mqttClient = new MQTTClient(512);
```

to

```
mqttClient = new MQTTClient(6000);
```